# Electrical question regarding sconces

Tags: electrical

I recently had electrical work done by an electrician, he ran power from my current ceiling fan to some bookshelves where I will be adding sconces I was looking at the wiring and there is one solo black wire that is capped and not connected to the others, when I go to hook up the sconces should I add this solo wire to the other black or leave it capped? It was not stripped like the others so I assumed that it was not to be added- just want to double check. [image]

Comment: Where were you looking at the wiring?  Was there a white or gray wire also capped?  Can you sketch out a drawing of the wires you saw in which location(s)?

Comment: @JulieD add a picture of the wiring or a good drawing. We can't assume anything.

Comment: Talked to the electrician- leaving it capped